# Can I change the font used on the Windows 10 on screen keyboard?

Tags: windows-10, on-screen-keyboard

Is it possible to change the font of the keys on the on screek keyboard?  I have Win10 Pro ver. 1903.  When I activate the keyboard there's an OPTIONS button, but that doesn't have anything about fonts.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7, 8 there is a setting with font size. In windows 10 there is no option, probably in Windows 11 there is no virtual keyboard at all. Microsoft and their upgrades or downgrades.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1120720)

Answer (score -1):

On screen keyboard is just like your physical keyboard. The font depends on where you are typing.

If you are typing MS Word or wordpad you can just use the Home menu options to change the Font and font size. Or if you type in your browser or a web page and if there is no option to change font then you have to use the default font.

The Options in On Screen Keyboard does not provide settings to change font.